# Will it be possible to run unity compiz in virtual box or another virtual machine?

Tags: unity, 11.04, virtualbox, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run Unity in a virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17937/how-can-i-run-unity-in-a-virtual-machine)

11.04 comes with unity interface. I would like to test 11.04 without installing it on a hard drive. Will it be possible?

Comment: Relevant: [How can I run Unity in a virtual machine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17937/how-can-i-run-unity-in-a-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful approach to testing the next releae, 11.04 is to create a live Ubuntu system on a USB memory stick from the daily builds:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Unity is not the default desktop environment yet, but is scheduled to be so by Alpha1 on the 2nd December as far as I understand the release schedule: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyReleaseSchedule

As well as testing Ubuntu a Live USB stick, you can also use that live USB stick to install Ubuntu 11.04 onto a second USB stick, selecting manual partition during the install.

You can also [use TestDrive to automate testing](http://ubuntu.jr0cket.co.uk/testing) when Ubuntu 11.04 Unity desktop does work in VirtualBox.

Thank you

http://ubuntu.jr0cket.co.uk/testing

Comment: you will need one usb disk for live system and one for installing the live system on it.

Answer (score 8):

Unity 3D from 11.04 runs fine in [Virtual Box >=4.0.6](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) as tested with NVidia proprietary graphics driver on the host. 3D support is activated by installation of [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtual-box/22745#22745).

Comment: How do you activate 3D driver in virtual box? On my usb drive is natty incredible fast! :) wow

Comment: The open source ATI Radeon HD host drivers make for a good a experience

Comment: Correct link to Guest Additions pre-release for Virtual Box 4.0.5 is that http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.0.4/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.0.5-Xorg110.iso

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is experience it,rather than a Virtual machine, use the live CD

Comment: (Note there is not yet a Live CD available at this early point in the development of 11.04)

Comment: ohk..  didnt know about that. had only used the stablr LTS releases till now