# Virtualbox Guest (Win 7 host) locks up on network access

Tags: networking, 11.04, virtualbox

I've got Ubuntu 10.10 installed on a virtual machine (VirtualBox). It works great other than it locks up after 5-10 minutes of doing something over the network. This includes ssh and browsing. My typical test is to let pandora run in a browser in the virtualbox for as long as possible. Ussually within a couple songs the Ubuntu guest hangs and I cannot do anything to it other than power down the virtual machine. I've tried getting to a plain text tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>) to no avail. The virtual box appears to have completely hung.

Note the guest OS will run for days doing various things (mostly local development) without hanging. Only when doing something that requires network access does it hang.

Some Specs:
VirtualBox 3.2.12, Windows 7 w/8.00 GB Ram Intel i5 Quad Core (760@2.8 GHz)

[This issue](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=35214&start=0&sid=272b6119abfa9650fa5010d4c9999e92I) at the VirtualBox discussion board may possibly be related.
[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17937/why-cant-unity-run-in-virtual-machines) may be related, but seems more tied to 3D performance. Still it may imply I may need to upgrade to VirtualBox 4.0.0:

(I'll go ahead and experiment with this)

How can I get my guest to not freeze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close up my own question -- I ended up installing the Virtualbox 4 and Ubuntu 10.10. This is no longer an issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to play with the networking settings?.

Tell VirtualBox to emulate a different network adapter, or change the net type to bridge. Look in the advanced options of the Net submenu.

[image]

Sorry, I can't take an English screenshot, as I usually do them from inside that Virtual Machine.