# How do I install 12.04 in vmware

Tags: vmware, custom-installer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run Unity in a virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17937/how-can-i-run-unity-in-a-virtual-machine)

What do I need to download to run 12.04 LTS as a VM using VMware player v5.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

You should download one of the 12.04 LTS .iso images, then tell VMware to mount those as the CD-ROM  when booting.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player) on installing Ubuntu inside VMware Player

Please refer section "**Installing Ubuntu inside VMware Player on a non-Ubuntu OS**" on the above mentioned page.