# How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I've recently installed Ubuntu on Oracle's Virtualbox.  Now I want to install the guest additions.

I started up my Ubuntu guest OS, clicked "Devices" and chose "Install Guest Additions". Nothing happened, and I don't see the CD icon on my desktop.

How can I make this work?

Comment: After installing, [see here for how to check that it worked](http://askubuntu.com/a/489850/193272).

Answer (score 630, accepted):

> If you have trouble installing Ubuntu in a VirtualBox VM, because the installer window does not fit the low resolution screen size, you can move the window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

### Installing Guest additions from the repositories

In case we have installed the **OSE edition** of Virtual Box from the repositories we can add the [guest additions from the repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3205/higher-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox) in the **guest**. This will install guest additions matching the Virtual Box version as obtained from the repositories. It is **not recommended** to install these in newer releases of Virtual Box as obtained from the Oracle repository (see below).

Alternatively we can install the package **virtualbox-guest-additions-iso** in the **host** Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

The .iso file with an image of the OSE edition of the guest additions CD will install in the host directory `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`. Mount this .iso file as a CD in your virtual machine's settings. In the guest you will then have access to a CD-ROM with the installer.

### Installing Guest Additions from Virtual Box Manager

In case the Guest Additions fail to build we may have to install the Linux kernel headers (see [How do I install kernel header files?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75709/88802)) or [**build-essential** [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) tools in addition. It is also recommended to have [**dkms** [image: Install dkms]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dkms) installed (see below - Note 4). You can run this command in a terminal to install both:

```
sudo apt install build-essential dkms
```

Selecting *Devices -> Install Guest Additions* (or press <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> from the Virtual Box Manager) the Guest Additions CD .iso will be loaded but **not installed** in your guest OS. To install we need to run the installer script `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` as root or from the Autorun Prompt (see below).

---

#### GNOME Shell

To install the Guest Additions we will have a CD icon on our desktop as soon as the virtual drive is mounted:

[image]

Next step is to run the *autorun.sh* script (as root) on this **mounted** CD by opening the drive and clicking on the "Run Software" button. This will build and install the vbox kernel modules needed.

---

#### Unity

The guest additions is mounted as a virtual CD visible on the launcher:

[image]

In case the system is set up to autorun a CD it should just open the following autorun dialogue (if not select the CD symbol, choose open, then choose *Open Autorun Prompt*)

[image]

After having entered your credentials for root access the guest additions will build as seen from the terminal output:

[image]

Press <kbd>Return</kbd> to close the terminal.

---

> **Note 1**
> Guest Additions need a reboot of your guest OS to take effect.

> **Note 2**
> In some systems the Virtual Box Guest Additions CD icon may not be shown on the desktop, but will be accessible from the *Places* menu. If the CD still was not there you may have to manually add the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso as a CD-ROM in the Virtual Box Manager *Storage* menu.  In an Ubuntu host the disk image is in `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`.

> **Note 3**
> In some systems (e.g. when running **Xubuntu** guests) we may not have an *Autorun Prompt* for the mounted CD. Then we can install the guest additions by opening a terminal on the mounted guest additions .iso to run `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`. In **Lubuntu** or **Ubuntu Server** guests we additionally need to install the GNU C compiler ([gcc](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc) [image: Install gcc]) and the [make](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/make) [image: Install make] utility in the guest system to be able to compile the guest additions.

> **Note 4**
> Running **DKMS** in the guest OS will keep Guest Additions installed after a guest kernel update. It is not a prerequisite for Guest Additions but if used it should be installed **before** we install the Guest Additions.

---

### Installing Guest Additions from a Terminal##

In case Guest Additions are not installed properly we may not be able to boot to the GUI. In this case we need to boot holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to access the Grub menu where we access a root shell as depicted in the following question (we do need to mount the filesystem read/write to proceed):

- [How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

The Guest Additions .iso file needs to be installed on `/dev/cdrom` from the Virtual Box Manager (see above). We then may install Guest Additions by typing the following commands:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt              # or any other mountpoint
cd /mnt
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
reboot
```

---

### Remove Guest Additions

In case something went wrong with installing the guest additions, or the guest OS can not boot after installing we may have to remove the additions. This can also be done from a [root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) by running an uninstallation script located in the **guest** `/opt` directory.

```
cd /opt/<VirtualBoxAdditions-x.x.xx>/
sudo ./uninstall.sh
```

Replace `x.x.xx` with your current version of guest additions.

Comment: I came across this answer while trying to install Guest Additions on Ubuntu Server. One step is missing if you need to install on server: run sudo apt-get install dkms first. (ref http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp19765808)

Comment: I tried your solution for ubuntu 12.10 server as guest and mac os x as host. Virtual box is 4.2.6. I am unable to to get the shared folders to work. somehow the guest additions are not working. Even Devices > Install Guest Additions did not work too. Not even the package virtualbox-guest-additions helped. Every attempt to run the iso GuestAdditions.iso does NOT lead to the iso showing up under /media/cdrom. Please advise.

Comment: @kimsia: you need to **mount** the .iso in your server first. After that you can install the GA with `sudo ./<mountpoint>/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Comment: @Takkat the mounting cannot work at all. In other news, i finally found a way to make everything work.http://superuser.com/a/527508/8184 so thank you for answering me. Appreciate it greatly :)

Comment: @kimisa: please note that the method you linked to will **not** install the most recent guest addition but those available from Ubuntu repositories (which would be 4.1.18 for 12.10 and 4.1.22 for 13.04). In case your host Virtual Box release is newer it is **not recommended** to run older versions of Guest Additions (but they will mostly still work).

Comment: @gertvdijk thank you for your effort but I deliberately left out the headers and build parts because in a vanilla default Ubuntu installation we **do not need these**. GA build fine without any further steps to take (this is different in Xubuntu and Lubuntu only). DKMS is supposed to help when ubpdating kernels but for some reasons we still always have to rebuild the GAs after a kernel update.

Comment: Ok this doesnt work at all. tested on ubuntu 32 and 64 versions 14.04.

And works only http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm/99479#99479

Comment: please specify which version.

Comment: sorry had to -1 this one. looks like a collection of "everything"

Comment: @IIIIIllllllllIlllllIIIIIIIIlll: sure - covering everything is all a "canonical" Q&A. is about. Anything missing, anything outdated?

Comment: In order to build guest additions on Ubuntu 14.04.4 Server, I needed to first do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install make gcc`.

Comment: On Ununtu 16.04, when I `apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`, it suggests to uninstall vmware first. this seems dangerous, will i loose data or settings to my existing vm-mashines?

Comment: @rubo77 this is a dependency issue brought in by vmware... definitely not related to installing the guest additions ISO file.

Comment: Yes it is, because this is the message, if you try to install the guest additions iso in the host system, which seems wrong. It worked after i installed the ISO in the guest system

Comment: @rubo77 it is a bug in the vmware dependencies. Installing an installer ISO in the **guest** is a waste of space.

Comment: So you should describe, how to get around this bug

Comment: @rubo77 alternatively we can install the guest-utils in the guest as was said in another answer I linked to above. Anyway, in the long run installing the regularly updated versions of virtualbox from the Oracle repository turned out to be better for me.

Comment: @Takkat Further to your comment from 26 June 2013, what about Xubuntu? Specifically, if I precede the GA script with `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-virtual dkms` just in case, is it safe? (Note: `linux-headers-virtual` includes `linux-headers-generic` as a dependency, and the latter is somehow [smart to sync with the kernel version, as opposed to `linux-headers-$(uname -r)`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files#comment444517_268710).) E.g. I've read that it might cause a dependency knot like [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/347588/193272).

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: I never had to manually install the headers in any guest - but if for any reason you must then **on Ubuntu** `linux-headers-virtual` and `linux-headers-generic` are just transitional packages pointing to the appropriate kernel headers. You also get these with installing `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` there should be no difference, and not dependency issues.

Comment: You don't need to install the ISO on the host. You can just do it on the guest then mount it with the `mount` command.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used a combination: 1) I used the CD in VB to map the .iso to it 2) used the terminal to go to the /mnt directory and do the *.run to install and then rebooted. Wish this guest additions nonsense would be put to bed once and for all.

Answer (score 120):

You could also try the following (this worked for me after I had to reinstall the Guest Addtitions after Update Manager killed them). Solution found here:

http://www.unixmen.com/install-guest-addition-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat-fix/

In summary:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-x11
```

This found and updated the correct version of the VirtualBox Guest Additions and my system seems to work properly again, and I'm assuming this will also work if Guest Additions are failing to install from the menu item.

One other thing of note. I originally tried to run this under the fish shell - make sure you're using bash (i.e. type "bash" into the terminal before you start).

---

Note on more recent systems, the command has been changed to

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Comment: your answer helped even though i was installing in a fresh installation ubuntu server. thank you. http://superuser.com/questions/527507/use-ubuntu-server-as-web-server-on-mac-os-x-via-virtualbox

Comment: The package is called `virtualbox-guest-x11` on more recent systems. I think this should be the accepted answer, because guest additions from ISO might not auto-update, in contrast to those installed using `apt-get`.

Comment: Note that I didn't have to install `build-essentials` on a freshly installed 14.04, and linux-headers were already installed. So running `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11` on the guest system was all I had to do.

Comment: I liked to use this method for the mentioned reason. However, it didn't work for me on `OSX` host (10.9.3) and Ubuntu 12.04 guest on VirtualBox (4.3.12). I had to use `ISO` installation http://askubuntu.com/a/22745/24203 (otherwise got `not such device error` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492466/how-to-mount-virtualbox-shared-folder-on-ubuntu-server-10-04-gui-sbin-mount-vb)

Comment: Ok this worked for me. ubuntu 32 and 64 versions 14.04

Comment: worked for me too, ubuntu 14.04 64
host Win7 64

Comment: strange thing, every time I reboot both machines (guest and host) I need to reinstall the guest to seamless mode work as expected.

Comment: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11, I am using this one and works.

Comment: The command "sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)" didn't work for me. The (uname -r) thing didn't work.

Comment: I can't copy and paste what I typed just yet but here it is:
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11 xorg-video-abi-15 xserver-xorg-core libcheese*

Answer (score 45):

Within the guest operating system, install the package `virtualbox-guest-dkms`.  For example, using the Terminal application, type `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms`.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14 LTS.

Comment: Worked for me for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.1. Make sure to reboot the machine after the installation. worked seemelessly.

Comment: Worked on 16.04.4 (although still need to futz around with graphics settings ...)

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.0.4.1LTS. I still can't copy and paste things from the host to the guest though (also not with any of the other methods mentioned here); shouldn't that work after this?

Comment: Works like a charm you beauty @ChrisJ <3

Comment: works on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 27):

Here are the manual steps to install [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) kernel modules inside the VM:

1. Download the ISO file, e.g.

   ```
   wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.20/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.20.iso -P /tmp
   ```
2. Mount the ISO file:

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.20.iso /mnt
   ```
3. Run installer (add `-x` after `sh` to debug):

   ```
   sudo sh /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   ```

To find the right version of ISO file, check it at: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/

---

If you're using Vagrant, installation is much simpler by following these commands:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
vagrant up
vagrant vbguest
```

Comment: These steps finally allowed me to have a full screen terminal. My host OS is Windows 7, VirtualBox version 5.1. My guest OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I also have the following two lines in /etc/default/grub: GRUB_GFX_MODE=1600x1200 and GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

Comment: Definitely an underrated answer -- super straightforward and will allow you to install a newer version of the Guest Additions than may be available in your apt repo.  Also, no need to add a virtual CD-ROM drive to your guest!

Comment: Best answer. IDK why all the other answers take unnecessary steps like building from source or creating virtual drives.

Comment: I added a variation of this to my Vagrant provisioning script.  Works perfect.

Comment: Great post! Using Vagrant I found I can specify `vagrant-vbguest` as a plugin in my `Vagrantfile`: Here's I've specified it as part of a list (so other plugins can be specified if needed),
`config.vagrant.plugins = [ "vagrant-vbguest", ]`

Answer (score 24):

The *standard* "virtualbox-guest-additions" package on the .iso provided by *Oracle*, has general tools for different Guest Operating Systems...

However, Ubuntu has its own dedicated **Ubuntu-specific** Guest Addon package(s)...
named `virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms and ..-x11 and ..-utils` .

These 'virtualbox-ose-guest-*' packages  are DKMS aware.. `"(DKMS is a framework designed to allow individual kernel modules to be upgraded without changing the whole kernel.)"`

Here is the link to a question I asked 5-6 months ago on this issue... [How can I get Compiz to work in a VirtualBox VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10519/how-can-i-get-compiz-to-work-in-a-virtualbox-vm)

Comment: I get "Unable to locate package virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms". Do I need to add an apt repo?

Comment: I think all you need to install on newer Ubuntus is the package `virtualbox-guest-x11`, which will draw in any other required dependencies.

Comment: It's now called `virtualbox-guest-dkms`. By the way, this is the only acceptable answer in this thread to me as this is the only way my guest additions worked in VBox. I've added my user to vboxusers group in advance, this might helped?

Answer (score 19):

Here are the steps I ran which finally worked, but as user named 'pcworld' stated above it may have been the case that only the last command was actually required. I'll never know, but I want to share in case this helps anyone else:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

And don't forget to set your VirtualBox instance to use like 128MB video ram and Enable 3D Acceleration under the "Display" settings section for your instance, for good performance.

Comment: After installing docker in vagrant I had that error with Guest Addition. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` did the trick. Thanks Clay.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me for a Ubuntu Server 14.04 guest VM (no GUI):

*Edit: also works with Ubuntu Server 15.04 and 16.04*

1) Install dkms. From the guest run:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

2) From the VirtualBox VM window menu select: Devices --> Insert Guest Additions CD image...

3) Use blkid to identify the CD-ROM device. From the guest run:

```
sudo blkid
```

One of the lines in the output should look like this:

```
/dev/sr0: LABEL="VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.16_95972" TYPE="iso9660"
```

The first part (`/dev/sr0`) is the name of the CD-ROM device.

4) Mount the CD (replace `/dev/sr0` by the device name found above):

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/
```

5) Run the Guest Additions installer:

```
sudo /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

6) Reboot the guest.

Comment: `sudo sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`  The `sh` was needed because the CD had been mounted without execute permission.

Comment: Hello @DavidLevesque , I've been tried in 16.04 but unfortunately I cannot get it run. Also I tried with `--nox11` parameters. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @efkan Unless you provide more details, I have no idea. It worked for me with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @DavidLevesque you're right :) I use VirtualBox v5.0.26 on Windows 10. And I install Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 in VirtualBox. (The server doesn't have X Window System) Then I followed the steps that are over here: http://en.ig.ma/notebook/2012/virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-server    . Then I reboot and try to perform copy-paste action but I cannot see any action. Thanks.

Comment: @efkan I suppose it doesn't work on a real console.

Answer (score 12):

The procedure is quite simple.

In Virtual Box menu select **Devices** > **Insert Guest Additions CD Image...**.

The following popup will appear on your Ubuntu desktop :

[image: guest addition popup]

Select <kbd>Run</kbd> and Guest Additions will automatically be installed.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on Oracle VM 5.0 on Windows 10. Only 2 clicks..... thank you!

Comment: This is the best answer, because it ensures that the Guest Additions are updated for and appropriate for your specific version of VirtualBox. Ubuntu's package and the `wget` URLs in the other answers can be outdated.

Comment: Works for me  in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 10):

I think the right way to do this right now (2020-Apr-27) with the newest stable Ubuntu (20.04) and the current Virtualbox (6.1.6) is to just do the following:

`sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-utils`

I just did that and it worked.

I guess this won't get a lot of attention down here but at least if somebody searches for 20.04 they might be able to find some more recent information. ;)

Comment: This is quite large: `457 newpackages with 154 MB to download, 867 MB of additional disk space`, I suggest to add `--no-install-recommends` which results in just 30MB download and 300MB

Comment: and `virtualbox-guest-utils` is not needed

Comment: @rubo77 Might be true. Are you sure? What is it for? It seems mount.vboxsf might be required for mounting a shared folder? But the dependencies are mostly on the other two anyway.

Comment: Not sure anymore, if it's needed

Answer (score 8):

The `virtualbox-guest-additions` package has to be installed. Furthermore, it *may appear* that nothing has happened, but all the "Install Guest Additions" button do is mounting the cdrom. You should open the File manager (Nautilus / Dolphin), select the "CD device" and run the installer.

Answer (score 3):

## For Lubuntu 16.04 users inside Ubuntu 16.04 Virtualbox

After trying many of the main-stream generic instructions I found [Lubuntu specific instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/3rdParty):

### Install Virtualbox Guest Additions onto a Lubuntu Virtual Machine

First step: Install required software

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make gcc
```

Next, use Virtualbox to download the Guest Additions, then select "Install Guest Additions" from the Virtualbox menu.

If the VBOXADDITIONS cd does not pop up in File Manager, Use File Manager to open the contents of the VBOXADDITIONS cd, then open a terminal there, by going to File Manager's menu and selecting 'Open Current Folder in Terminal'

```
sudo sh VBoxLinux*
```

reboot and enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the guest additions .iso, mount it in VirtualBox via the guest OS settings. Then start the guest OS and run the vboxwindowsadditions-x86 or amd64 exe.

Answer (score -1):

Open Ubuntu in VirtualBox. Open FireFox and go here:
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/

Find your version of Virtualbox and click the link to open it.

Download your version of VBoxGuestAdditions (iso):

Open it in Archive manager and extract files.

Run: `sudo VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Reboot.

This works if you can't open the iso file in VirtualBox (ISO9660 error).